# Why is my django template tag not able to iterate my object across a model

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm having an issue getting my template to produce a table that includes the models name, a count of the number of child models to that parent, and then a sum of a field in that child model. I've gotten the first two to return the desired output, but the last two only yield an empty space in the cell. Can't figure out where I'm missing it.

MODELS.PY FILE

```
class Employee(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(default="hulkhoganicon.jpg", null=True, blank=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname
class Event(models.Model):
STATUS = (
    ('Appointment Set', 'Appointment Set'),
    ('Hot Lead', 'Hot Lead'),
    ('Booked', 'Booked'),
    ('Lost Sale', 'Lost Sale'),
    ('X-Dated', 'X-Dated'),
)
PACKAGE = (
    ('1st Package', '1st Package'),
    ('2nd Package', '2nd Package'),
    ('3rd Package', '3rd Package'),
    ('4th Package', '4th Package'),
)
ADDONS = (
    ('None','None'),
    ('2nd Setup', '2nd Setup'),
    ('Uplighting', 'Uplighting'),
    ('Monogram', 'Monogram'),
    ('Intelligent Lighting', 'Intelligent Lighting'),
    ('Other', 'Other'),
)
employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
eventType = models.ForeignKey(EventType, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
teamAssigned = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
eventName = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
date_of_event = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True)
date_of_appt = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True)
date_booked = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
package = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=PACKAGE)
price = models.FloatField(null=True)
addons = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=ADDONS)
addonPrice = models.FloatField(null=True)
addonOverage = models.FloatField(null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
notes = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

def __str__(self):
    return self.eventName
```

VIEWS.PY FILE

```
def teamDashboard(request):
events = Event.objects.all()
employees = Employee.objects.all()

total_employees = employees.count()
total_events = events.count()
events_sum = events.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
booked_sum = events.filter(status='Booked').aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']

Green_events = events.filter(teamAssigned__name='Green').count()
Green_events_sum = events.filter(teamAssigned__name='Green').aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
Green_booked_sum = events.filter(teamAssigned__name='Green', status='Booked').aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']

Blue_events = events.filter(teamAssigned__name='Blue').count()
Blue_events_sum = events.filter(teamAssigned__name='Blue').aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']

Orange_events = events.filter(teamAssigned__name='Orange').count()
Orange_events_sum = events.filter(teamAssigned__name='Orange').aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']

Purple_events = events.filter(teamAssigned__name='Purple').count()
Purple_events_sum = events.filter(teamAssigned__name='Purple').aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']

Booked = events.filter(status='Booked').count()
Appointment_Set = events.filter(status='Appointment Set').count()
Appt_set_sum = events.filter(status='Appointment Set').aggregate(Sum('price'))
Date = datetime.now()

context = {'Date':Date, 'total_employees':total_employees, 'events':events, 'employees':employees,
           'total_events':total_events, 'Booked':Booked, 'Appointment_Set':Appointment_Set,
           'Appt_set_sum':Appt_set_sum, 'Green_events':Green_events, 'Blue_events':Blue_events,
           'Orange_events':Orange_events,'Purple_events':Purple_events, 'Green_events_sum':Green_events_sum,
           'Blue_events_sum':Blue_events_sum, 'Orange_events_sum':Orange_events_sum,
           'Purple_events_sum':Purple_events_sum,'Green_booked_sum':Green_booked_sum, 'events_sum':events_sum,
           'booked_sum':booked_sum,
           }
context['segment'] = 'teamDashboard'
return render(request, 'accounts/team-dashboard.html', context)
```

TEAM-DASHBOARD.HTML FILE

```
<tbody>
                        {% for employee in employees %}
                            {% if employee.team.name == "Green" %}
                                <tr>
                                  <td></td>
                                  <td>{{employee.firstname}}</td>
                                  <td>{{employee.event_set.count}}</td>
                                  <td>{{events_sum.employee_set}}</td>
                                  <td>{{employee.events.booked_sum}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endif %}
                        </tbody>
                        {% endfor %}
```

I'm just starting out with Django so thank you in advance if I'm making a really dumb mistake!

Comment: `events_sum` is just a number (a sum aggregation). How do you expect `events_sum.employee_set` to work?

Comment: I'm trying to pull the sum of the price of the events for each individual employee in Employees.